# in c: create a loop to pop linked nodes off the stack

Tags: c

I am trying to implement my pop() function in my c program. My program uses a linked stack of nodes. My pop and push functions seem to work fine, but when I try to run this:

```
    printf(fp, "%s", (pop(&ptr)));
```

I get NULL printed. My pop takes in (node **ptr) and returns *char, and this code compiles fine. Where am I off?

Comment: do you get warnings? I  would guess that you really want `printf(fp, "%s", (pop(&ptr)));` if pop takes a pointer to a pointer

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and this http://sscce.org/ , then update your question.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Show your actual code; that is the only way to debug this apart from the obvious mismatch with `printf` and `fprintf`

Answer (score 1):

if you want print on stdout

```
printf(fp, "%s", (pop(*ptr))) ==> printf("%s", (pop(*ptr)))
```

if you want to print into file, You need to use [fprintf(](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf))

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", (pop(*ptr)))
```